# How do you avoid errors do an automatic grading script?

Tags: python

This is my second beginner python course, so I'm learning!  For most things I'm working with Python notebooks because I feel it has more flexibility.  The actual program is Coursera.  I recently transferred the following code from python notebooks (that worked fine) back to Coursera, and I'm getting syntax errors.  Not the first time.  How do I avoid this?  Looking for any advice.

"TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"

```
def email_list(domains):
    emails = []
    for provider, user in domains.items():
        for each_user in user: 
            new_user=("{}@{} ".format(each_user,provider))
            emails.append(new_user)
    return(emails)

print(email_list({"gmail.com": ["clark.kent", "diana.prince", "peter.parker"], "yahoo.com": ["barbara.gordon", "jean.grey"], "hotmail.com": ["bruce.wayne"]}))
```

Comment: Use an IDE like PyCharm, it should format things automatically for you.

Comment: Cannot reproduce error from snippet given

Comment: That is correct.  There is no error in python notebooks.  It works.  The question is really about the training program - Coursera, which is causing me a syntax error.  As a beginner, I have no idea how to solve this mysterious bug that only exists on one platform.  I can't use a development platform - I have to submit code on the Coursera platform.

Comment: I can't spot any possible indentation issues, although it claims you are using both \t tabs and spaces (which you aren't allowed to do).  Maybe check if you accidentally inserted tabs into the code while working on it on Coursera (IDEs usually normalize tabs and space indents for you, while Coursera's editor may not)?  There's also a space after `user: ` although that shouldn't cause any problems

Answer (score 1):

I have faced such problems in the past and here is what I did, after pasting your code in Coursera, try deleting every space and tab from your code and retype them for example, delete the spaces in the def line until you have this line

```
def email_list(domains):emails = []
```

after this line pressing return or enter right after the colon will give you the right indentation and hopefully, your code will run smoothly.